# How do I allow form submission with the submit button and the enter key?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the user to be able to submit a form by clicking the submit button or the enter key. I'm using jQuery and here's my code:

```
    <input id="weather"/>
    <button id="myButton" type="text">Response</button>
</div>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $("#myButton").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#myButton").submit();
        }
    });

    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function() {
        if (document.getElementById("weather").value.toLowerCase() != "nice" && document.getElementById("weather").value.toLowerCase() != "crappy") {
            alert("Please enter only either 'Nice' or 'Crappy.'");
        } else if (document.getElementById("weather").value.toLowerCase() == "nice") {
            alert("GREAT! Let's go the the BEACH!!");
        } else {
            alert("Hmm. That blows. Well then, I just won't be going outside today.")
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who commented - figured it out by looking at everyone's suggestions:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the whole thing in a `form` tag and change the button type to `submit`. Enter will then submit the form.

```
<form> 
    <input id="weather"/>
    <button id="myButton" type="submit">Response</button>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ksnaepz/)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help (that goes for everybody who has). I tried your solution first and, while it works on JSFiddle, I can't replicate the solution on my end. My browser is Chrome and I'm not getting the alert messages. The enter key is working though.

Comment: AHHHH. So sorry, it definitely worked (after I remembered that I was using a bit of jQuery in my code....). UG, the life of a newb. Pasted in what I needed and shazaaaaayam. Works great! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="weather" />
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Response"/>
```

The onclick script should be

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick(function(){
  if (document.getElementById("weather").value.toLowerCase() !="nice" && document.getElementById("weather").value.toLowerCase() !="crappy") {
    alert("Please enter only either 'Nice' or 'Crappy.'");
  } 
  else if (document.getElementById("weather").value.toLowerCase() =="nice"){
    alert("GREAT! Let's go the the BEACH!!");
  } else {
    alert("Hmm. That blows. Well then, I just won't be going outside today.")
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use submit type of button. It should not be a text type.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to wrap input and button with form and check input only in case of form submit like:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#weatherForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $weatherElement = $('#weather');

    if ($weatherElement.val() != "Nice" && $weatherElement.val() != "Crappy") {
      alert("Please enter only either 'Nice' or 'Crappy.'");
    } else if ($weatherElement.val() == "Nice") {
      alert("GREAT! Let's go the the BEACH!!");
    } else {
      alert("Hmm. That blows. Well then, I just won't be going outside today.")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" id="weatherForm">
  <input id="weather" name="weather" />
  <input type="submit" id="myButton" value="Response" />
</form>
```